# Javascript how to rename object key maintaining value and position

Tags: javascript, object

I have this object:

```
let obj = {one: 1, two: 2, three: 3, eight: 4, five: 5}
```

what I need is to rename `eight` with `four` keeping the same value and the same position. I did this:

```
let obj = {one: 1, two: 2, three: 3, eight: 4, five: 5}
let tmp = obj[eight];
delete obj.eight;
obj.four = tmp;
```

but obviously it will return: `{one: 1, two: 2, three: 3, five: 5, four: 4}` instead of `{one: 1, two: 2, three: 3, four: 4, five: 5}`.

I thougth saving the properties on a key-value array and then reconstructing the whole object, but this way wouldn't be efficient, since I can't tell how many properties the object can store. ANy hint on this?

Comment: Keys in object are not sorted as you might think

Comment: "Position" is not something you can control. There's a spec for the ordering of property names, but it's not adaptable to your application semantics; it is what it is.

Comment: If you need a guarnteed order you should use [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

Comment: What is the semantic goal / problem you are solving using this? I think you should store the data differently.

Comment: If you need order, use an array.

Comment: the thing is I am getting this object from an API, and it returns objects instead of arrays

Comment: Then extract the keys into an array, sort the array according to your needs, and use the array to extract property values in your desired order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JS since ECMAScript 2015 the order of iteration is the same as insertion order (for string and Symbol keys). So you need to re-create the complete object:

```
let obj = {one: 1, two: 2, three: 3, eight: 4, five: 5};

obj = Object.keys(obj)
  .reduce((a, key) => ({
    ...a,
    [key === 'eight' ? 'four' : key]: obj[key],
  }), {});

console.log(obj); // prints {one: 1, two: 2, three: 3, four: 4, five: 5}
```

If that is not efficent enough for the problem you are solving, I suppose you store your data differently.